# How do I access my Astra DB from netlify in Ania Kubow's Netflix clone tutorial?

Tags: netlify, datastax-astra

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8COh40v2jU&t=3857s).

I am stuck at 1:04.

Ania is able to return data from here datastax db.

I am able to start the netlify dev server on localhost 8888, but I get a page that returns an authentication required message.

```
{
errors: [
"Authentication required"
]
}
```

I am logged in and connected to datastax. I am using the correct authentication token in the graphql playground (it's odd to me that I am required to do this to be able to see the data in local host).

What else is required to authenticate in order to see the local host returning data from datastax?[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8COh40v2jU&t=3857s)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you've missed a step from Ania's tutorial. For what it's worth, the full instructions are published on GitHub -- https://github.com/kubowania/netflix-clone-graphql-datastax.

Make sure that you create the `.env` file in [step 10](https://github.com/kubowania/netflix-clone-graphql-datastax#10-start-the-project) to make sure it contains the application token you created in [step 3](https://github.com/kubowania/netflix-clone-graphql-datastax#3-create-a-security-token) and the link to your GraphQL Playground in [step 4](https://github.com/kubowania/netflix-clone-graphql-datastax#4-create-table-genre-with-graphql):

```
ASTRA_DB_APPLICATION_TOKEN={ your_token }
ASTRA_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT={ your_endpoint }
```

Make sure you follow every single step in the instructions or you won't be able to complete the tutorial. Cheers!